# Как взять переменные после отправки формы?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, html, javascript

Есть страница, на которую передаётся номер заказа, его описание, цена и пара других параметров. Есть форма, в которой поле для пользователя, при загрузке страницы я пишу данные по оплате в бд, на случай если пользователь экстренно завершит работу браузера и я смог с ним потом связаться. От пользователя требуется вбить в форму некоторые данные, которые я потом хочу добавить в ту же строку, в бд, что и данные по оплате. Проблема в том, что после отправки формы предыдущие переменные пропадают и в бд записываются пустые строки. Помогите найти проблему.

[>>> Код здесь >>>](http://jsfiddle.net/chum3jf2/1/)

Comment: Единственный вариант использовать сессии или куки, или есть другой способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не увидел в коде формы ни одного поля, кроме `t_url`, которые бы передавались. Да, Вы их получаете, но не отправляете.

```
    $id = $_GET['m_operation_id'];
```

Но в форме нет ни одного элемента с таким именем.